# Most Efficient way to convert jdbctemple result to json?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

One Way is to convert the `List< Map < String, Object>>` into `List(object);` Given Below

```
List<Map<String, Object>> ls = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);

List<Users> ls_o =  new ArrayList<>(ls_o);
        for (Map<String, Object> row : ls) {
        ls_o.add(row);

        }
 return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(ls_o, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Is there any effiecient way to directly convert the jdbcTemplate result into json object?

Comment: Use GSON parser. Return the query result as String and parse that: `public static JsonObject getGsonJsonObject( String jsonString ) {
        if ( StringUtils.isNotBlank( jsonString ) ) {
            JsonParser gsonJSONParser = new JsonParser();
            return ( JsonObject ) gsonJSONParser.parse( jsonString );
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using Maven as you build script. Add following dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Modify Code as shown below

```
   private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ResponseEntity myMethod(){

    List<Map<String, Object>> ls = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);        
    final String str = mapper.writeValueAsString(ls);
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(str, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

However if you are using Spring 4+ MVC, I would recommend you to use @RestController

Which does most of the job for you here is an example for you, here is simple example

```
   @RestController
   class MyTestClass{

    @RequestMapping("/myMethod")
    public List<Map<String, Object>> myMethod(){

        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);        
    }
```

}

**Note:** In Both Above cases you need to convert The Object class to a Exact class to work.

Comment: Works without any effort. Thanks!